A three-member ring is easier to form than a four- member one, although the former has a larger ring strain. Why?
Four-membered heterocycles are more difficult to synthesize by than the three-membered heterocycles despite having lower angle strain than the 3 membered rings. Why is it so?

Can you provide a source or example?

@3red2green
"Moreover, four-membered heterocycles are more difficult to synthesize by direct intramolecular cyclization than the three-membered heterocycles because ring forming ability falls off with the chain length."
https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-72276-9_7
If that's the case, 5 or 6 six membered rings should be harder to form than 3 or 4 membered, which are not. So, there must another factor involved.

Speculation (didn't read the chapter) "easier" is about e.g., for expoxidations often of concerted mechanism (either by MCPBA, or via halohydrine), rather than a sequential (Corey). Ketenes dimerize and are used to synthesize $\beta$ lactams by [2+2] cycloadditions for long, too. Can you amend the question i) in which section of the book the authors provide state this, ii) with a specific reaction scheme? Maybe the molecules too stiff/unflexible to bring the reaction partners close enough (because of intra- instead of intermolecular).

Cyclopropanes are easy to synthesize from double bonds and diazomethane, like :

There is no similar reaction for the synthesis of cyclobutanes

The question was asked for heterocycles...

Cyclopropanes are not heterocycles.
